# How do I get one cell value from $wpdb?

Tags: wordpress

I can't figure out what function should I use, get_var, get_results or may be I shouldn't use them at all, but I neet to echo just one value from one cell only, like 9000.

```
<?php $apartprice_this = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta   WHERE post_id=%d AND meta_key=%s", the_ID(),'price'));
echo $apartprice_this; ?>
```

but now, I don't know where it takes, but it returns me "8Array", what is that?

Answer (score 0):

WP function get_results returns an array.
To echo any value in that array you should use the field key as:

```
foreach( $apartprice_this as $results ) 
{
 echo $results->field_key;
}
```